# "Space" and "time" part of a $ 2 $-form on a product manifold $ \mathbb R\times S $

Tags: differential-geometry

I'm working through exercises 50 and 51 in Baez, Muniain, *Gauge Fields, Knots and Gravity*. Let $ M $ be a manifold and suppose we can write $ M $ as a product $ M = \mathbb R\times S $ of a "time" $ 1 $-dimensional manifold $ \mathbb R $ with some "space" manifold $ S $.

Take a $ 2 $-form $ F $ on $ M $. Exercise 50 asks to show that $ F $ can be written in a unique way as
$$
F = B + E\wedge\mathrm dt 
$$
where $ B $ is some $ 2 $-form, $ E $ is some $ 1 $-form, and $ \mathrm dt $ is the $ 1 $-form (globally) defined as
$$
\mathrm dt_{(t,p)} = \Bigl(\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\Big\rvert_{(t,p)}\Bigr)^*
$$
for any $ (t,p)\in \mathbb R\times S $, where $ (\partial/\partial t)\rvert_{(t,p)} $ is the tangent vector in $ \mathrm T_{(p,q)}(\mathbb R\times S) $ that correspond to the pair of tangent vectors $ \bigl((\partial/\partial t)\rvert_t,0\bigr) $ in $ \mathrm T_t\mathbb R\otimes \mathrm T_pS $ under the canonical identification $ \mathrm T_{(p,q)}(\mathbb R\times S)\cong \mathrm T_t\mathbb R\oplus \mathrm T_pS $.

I thought that the Künneth isomorphism might be lurking behind this fact. Indeed, we have a chain of isomorphisms
$$
\bigwedge\nolimits^2\mathrm T_{(t,p)}^*(\mathbb R\times S)\cong \bigwedge\nolimits^2\mathrm (T_t^*\mathbb R\oplus \mathrm T_p^*S)\cong \overbrace{\bigwedge\nolimits^2 \mathrm T_t^*\mathbb R}^{= 0}\oplus \bigl(\mathrm T_t^*\mathbb R\otimes \mathrm T_p^* S\bigr)\oplus \bigwedge\nolimits^2 \mathrm T_p^*S\cong \bigl(\mathrm T_t^*\mathbb R\otimes \mathrm T_p^* S\bigr)\oplus \bigwedge\nolimits^2 \mathrm T_p^*S
$$
so that in local coordinates $ (x^\mu) $, $ x^0 = t $, the form $ F $ can be formally written
$$
F_{(t,p)} = \sum_I\overbrace{F_I(t,p)}^{\text{some coefficient}}\bigl(\mathrm dt\oplus \mathrm dx^{i_1}\bigr)\wedge \bigl(\mathrm dt\oplus \mathrm dx^{i_2}\bigr)
$$
where $ I = (i_1 < i_2) $ (the sum is over all such multi-indices). Then $ F_{(t,p)} $ corresponds to
$$
F_{(t,p)}\leftrightarrow \sum_I F_I(t,p)\Bigl(\mathrm dt\otimes\bigl(\mathrm dx^{i_2} - \mathrm dx^{i_1}\bigr)\Bigr)\oplus \mathrm dx^I
$$
which *looks like* the decomposition of $ F $ I'm trying to find.

Am I on the right track?

Answer (score 1):

No, I would not say you're on the right track. It is not possible to prove a decomposition $\Omega^k(M)\cong (\mathbb{R}dt\wedge\Omega^{k-1}(S))\oplus \Omega^k(S)$ by proving an isomorphism of vector spaces. You need an isomorphism of vector bundles, or spaces of sections (as $C^\infty(M)$-modules).

So observe that the vector field $\partial_t$ gives rise to a linear map $\iota_{\partial_t}:\Omega^\bullet(M)\to\Omega^{\bullet-1}(M)$, i.e. an endomorphism of $\Omega^\bullet(M)$ which lowers degree by $1$. Now, it is a fact from linear algebra that $\Omega^\bullet(M)\cong\text{im }\iota_{\partial_t}\oplus\ker\iota_{\partial_t}$, and therefore in particular $\Omega^k(M)\cong \iota_{\partial_t}\Omega^{k+1}(M)\oplus (\mathbb{R}dt\wedge\Omega^{k-1}(S))$. The reason being, of course, that $\omega\in\mathbb{R}dt
\wedge\Omega^{k-1}(S)$ is a necessary and sufficient condition for $\omega\in\ker\iota_{\partial_t}$. This is the part you can prove in local coordinates. It is easy to see that $\iota_{\partial_t}\Omega^{k+1}(M)\cong\Omega^k(S)$. Hence, $\Omega^k(M)\cong\Omega^k(S)\oplus(\mathbb{R}dt\wedge\Omega^{k-1}(S))$. And this is the global result that you are after.